# How to find a maximum matching which considering the weight of vertex

Tags: graph-theory, matroids

First, if **G=(V,E)**, and **C** is the collection of all vertices set which can be covered by a matching in **G**.

I have proved that such **(V,C)** is a matroid.

And each vertex $v_i$ has a weight $w(v_i)$, how to How to find a matching where the weight of all covered vertices is maximum?

Answer (score 0):

Link to wikipedia [Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs):

In weighted bipartite graphs

In a weighted bipartite graph, each edge has an associated value. A maximum weighted bipartite matching is defined as a matching where the sum of the values of the edges in the matching have a maximal value. If the graph is not complete bipartite, missing edges are inserted with value zero. Finding such a matching is known as the assignment problem. The Hungarian algorithm solves the assignment problem and it was one of the beginnings of combinatorial optimization algorithms. It uses a modified shortest path search in the augmenting path algorithm. If the Bellman–Ford algorithm is used for this step, the running time of the Hungarian algorithm becomes O(V^2 E), or the edge cost can be shifted with a potential to achieve O(V^2 \log{V} + V E) running time with the Dijkstra algorithm and Fibonacci heap.

In general graphs

Main article: Edmonds's matching algorithm

There is a O(V^{2}E) time algorithm to find a maximum matching or a maximum weight matching in a graph that is not bipartite; it is due to Jack Edmonds, is called the paths, trees, and flowers method or simply Edmonds' algorithm, and uses bidirected edges. A generalization of the same technique can also be used to find maximum independent sets in claw-free graphs. Edmonds' algorithm has subsequently been improved to run in time O(√VE) time, matching the time for bipartite maximum matching.

Another (randomized) algorithm by Mucha and Sankowski, based on the fast matrix multiplication algorithm, gives O(V^{2.376}) complexity.

Comment: `A maximal matching can be found with a simple greedy algorithm`, how to do?

Comment: A maximal matchin is a matching such that no further edges could be added. You just iterate over each edge and check whether you can add it or not. This has nothing to do with maximal weight.

Comment: According to you question your're not looking for such a matching rather for the maximum weightend matching ( the matching with the maximal sum of weight on its edges).

Comment: Actually, vertex-weighted maximal matching

Comment: To obtain such a matching you will need to use a way more complicated algorithm. If your graph is not bipartite, you will have to use a variant of the [Blossom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#cite_note-blossom5-10) algorithm.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific algorithm to calculate the maximum vertex weight, but it should be possible to assigne and update weights of the edges depending on the gain, which would be obtained by adding the specific edge.